# Add fontsize to Redactor JS

Tags: javascript, redactor

I'm trying to add a button to change the font size in Redactor JS but it doesn't work. Here's my code to intialise Redactor :

```
$('#redactor_content').redactor({
                        buttons: buttons,
                        buttonsCustom: {
                          superscript: {
                              title: 'Superscript',
                              callback: function(obj, event, key) {
                                  obj.execCommand('superscript')
                              }
                          },
                          subscript: {
                              title: 'Subscript',
                              callback: function(obj, event, key) {
                                  obj.execCommand('subscript')
                              }
                          }
                        },
                        plugins: ['fontsize']
                    });
```

and this is my plugin :

```
RedactorPlugins.fontsize = {
init: function()
{
    var fonts = [10, 11, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 24, 28, 30];
    var that = this;
    var dropdown = {};

    $.each(fonts, function(i, s)
    {
        dropdown['s' + i] = { title: s + 'px', callback: function() { that.setFontsize(s); } };
    });

    dropdown['remove'] = { title: 'Remove font size', callback: function() { that.resetFontsize(); } };

    this.buttonAdd( 'fontsize', 'Change font size', false, dropdown);
},
setFontsize: function(size)
{
    this.inlineSetStyle('font-size', size + 'px');
},
resetFontsize: function()
{
    this.inlineRemoveStyle('font-size');
}
};
```

But nothing appears in the toolbar. Any idea? Did I do anything wrong?

Comment: What is in your `buttons` variable? Assuming that it is the array of button strings, did you add `Superscript` and `Subscript` to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this code before yuour plugin

```
if (!RedactorPlugins) var RedactorPlugins = {};

RedactorPlugins.fontsize = {
    init: function(){
        var fonts = [10, 11, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 24, 28, 30];
        var that = this;
        var dropdown = {};

        $.each(fonts, function(i, s){
            dropdown['s' + i] = { title: s + 'px', callback: function() { that.setFontsize(s); } };
        });

        dropdown['remove'] = { title: 'Remove font size', callback: function() { that.resetFontsize(); } };
        this.buttonAdd( 'fontsize', 'Change font size', false, dropdown);
    },
    setFontsize: function(size){
        this.inlineSetStyle('font-size', size + 'px');
    },
    resetFontsize: function(){
        this.inlineRemoveStyle('font-size');
    }
};
```

Also remove any extra code to ensure you're having a problem with the code in question.
Maybe also stick it in a document ready event

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(
    function()
    {
        $('#redactor_content').redactor({
            focus: true,
            plugins: ['fontsize']
        });
    }
);
</script>
```

Code works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the official "fontsize" plugin for that if you want: https://github.com/johnsardine/redactor-plugins

There are also other new plugins available:

```
fontcolor.js, fontsize.js and fontfamily.js
```

When included, you can use them like this:

```
elem.redactor({
      plugins: ['fontcolor', 'fontsize', 'fontfamily']
});
```